Sums Package Failing to Tokenize in Python
I am using the following code to summarize my text in Python. The code is being run in Jupyter Notebook. I have already install sumy using pip command.
pip install sumy nltk
python -m nltk.downloader punkt

from sumy.parsers.plaintext import PlaintextParser
from sumy.nlp.tokenizers import Tokenizer
from sumy.summarizers.lsa import LsaSummarizer
from io import StringIO

# Define the text to be summarized
text = """
Natural Language Processing (NLP) is a field of artificial intelligence that focuses on the interaction between computers and humans through natural language. The ultimate objective of NLP is to enable computers to understand, interpret, and respond to human language in a way that is both valuable and meaningful.
NLP is used to apply algorithms to identify and extract the natural language rules such that the unstructured language data is converted into a form that computers can understand. When the text has been provided, a computer can take many different approaches to process it. The algorithm can be a rule-based or a machine learning-based approach.
"""

# Use StringIO to simulate a file-like object
text_io = StringIO(text)

# Parse the text
parser = PlaintextParser.from_file(text_io, Tokenizer("english"))

# Initialize the LSA summarizer
summarizer = LsaSummarizer()

# Generate the summary (you can adjust the number of sentences)
summary = summarizer(parser.document, sentences_count=2)

# Print the summary
for sentence in summary:
    print(sentence) 

When I run the program I get the following error:
ame)
    662 def find_class(self, module, name):
    663     # Forbid every function
--> 664     raise pickle.UnpicklingError(f"global '{module}.{name}' is forbidden")

UnpicklingError: global 'copy_reg._reconstructor' is forbidden 

Any ideas!

this is because of tokenizer error change the tokenizer and the issue will be resolved

TLDR - this has been raised with sumy via GitHub
nltk's latest release (3.8.2) now restricts the use of pickled files.

sumy's Tokenizer initialisation calls nltk with a pickle file here
nltk's latest changes means a pickle file will raise the error you are receiving as it is restricted see here

For your code, as a temporary solution whilst sumy addresses this change on their end, you can create a temp Tokenizer class
from nltk.tokenize import PunktTokenizer
from sumy.nlp.tokenizers import Tokenizer

class MyTokenizer(Tokenizer):

    def _get_sentence_tokenizer(self, language):
        # Use the linked GitHub Issue's code where they have overridden this function

Also your step

python -m nltk.downloader punkt

should now be
python -m nltk.downloader punkt_tab

