Python package sumy throwing errors in Jupyter notebook
I am trying to use sumy to summarize text but keep getting weird issues. I am using the following code in my Jupyter Notebook.
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('punkt_tab')

import sumy 

from sumy.parsers.plaintext import PlaintextParser
from sumy.nlp.tokenizers import Tokenizer
from sumy.summarizers.lsa import LsaSummarizer

# Your text to summarize
text = """
Your long text here...
"""

# Create a PlaintextParser object
parser = PlaintextParser.from_string(text, Tokenizer("english"))

# Create an LsaSummarizer object
summarizer = LsaSummarizer()

# Summarize the text
summary = summarizer(parser.document, 3)  # Summarize to 3 sentences

# Print the summary
for sentence in summary:
    print(sentence)

But I get the error:
 UnpicklingError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 6
      3 from sumy.summarizers.lsa import LsaSummarizer
      5 text = "Your long text here..."
----> 6 parser = PlaintextParser.from_string(text, Tokenizer("english"))
      7 summarizer = LsaSummarizer()
      8 summary = summarizer(parser.document, 3)  # Summarize to 3 sentences

File ~/Desktop/sample_project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sumy/nlp/tokenizers.py:160, in Tokenizer.__init__(self, language)
    157 self._language = language
    159 tokenizer_language = self.LANGUAGE_ALIASES.get(language, language)
--> 160 self._sentence_tokenizer = self._get_sentence_tokenizer(tokenizer_language)
    161 self._word_tokenizer = self._get_word_tokenizer(tokenizer_language)

File ~/Desktop/sample_project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sumy/nlp/tokenizers.py:172, in Tokenizer._get_sentence_tokenizer(self, language)
    170 try:
    171     path = to_string("tokenizers/punkt/%s.pickle") % to_string(language)
--> 172     return nltk.data.load(path)
    173 except (LookupError, zipfile.BadZipfile) as e:
    174     raise LookupError(
    175         "NLTK tokenizers are missing or the language is not supported.\n"
    176         """Download them by following command: python -c "import nltk; nltk.download('punkt')"\n"""
    177         "Original error was:\n" + str(e)
    178     )

File ~/Desktop/sample_project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nltk/data.py:763, in load(resource_url, format, cache, verbose, logic_parser, fstruct_reader, encoding)
    761     resource_val = opened_resource.read()
    762 elif format == "pickle":
--> 763     resource_val = restricted_pickle_load(opened_resource.read())
    764 elif format == "json":
    765     import json

File ~/Desktop/sample_project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nltk/data.py:667, in restricted_pickle_load(string)
    662 """
    663 Prevents any class or function from loading.
    664 """
    665 from nltk.app.wordnet_app import RestrictedUnpickler
--> 667 return RestrictedUnpickler(BytesIO(string)).load()

   662 def find_class(self, module, name):
    663     # Forbid every function
--> 664     raise pickle.UnpicklingError(f"global '{module}.{name}' is forbidden")

UnpicklingError: global 'copy_reg._reconstructor' is forbidden


I added more text for the error.

Thanks for providing the full message; it changes everything. It appears that this question has been asked but did not receive any upvoted or accepted answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78862511

Can you [edit] your question to include your versions of nltk and sumy? If you don't know how to get that, scroll through some of these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20180543

Sumy requires the "punkt_tab" package in addition to "punkt." Paste this line just below nltk.download('punkt'):
nltk.download('punkt_tab')

Running your code with that change gave me the following output:
Your long text here...


Getting the same exact error.

Did you try to install theses specficis Tokens by using
python -c "import nltk; nltk.download('english')"


How can I run this from inside my Jupyter Notebook?

@johndoe Paste nltk.download('english') just below the rest of your nltk downloads.

I ran it and it said already up to date.

@John doe, FYI to hekp your Jupyter use in general, maybe not this specific issue: you probably can open a terminal using the launcher to also have a terminal where you can run such commands not in Jupyter. Or in Jupyter you can put a exclamation point if front of command lines to try and run them from in a Jupyter cell, like !python -c "import nltk; nltk.download('english')" (For some things though there is a magic equivalent you should use and not an exclamation. %pip and %conda are significant in this regard.)

If I run !python -c "import nltk; nltk.download('english')" in Jupyter I get [nltk_data] Error loading english: Package 'english' not found in
[nltk_data]     index
